# PHP DateTime error; cannot parse string

Tags: php

I have this DateTime cannot parse string error in php. i have tried applying solutions I read online but none has worked so far. My question is, is it possible for DateTime() to be disabled. Even the simplest code

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-5-5');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d);
```

Does not work.
I also tried using the static function createFromFormat(). And also I am not calling the DateTime class from a Class..so I do not need a back slash. What can I do please

Comment: mispelling echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: @Denny thanks for the correction but it still doesn't work. I have been on this for some days now. Had to come to stackoverflow for possible solution.

Comment: works fine to me, just copy paste your code

Comment: @MacBooc I tried it on another computer. It worked just fine but it doesn't work on mine. I am using Linux ubuntu 12.04

Comment: what kind of error did you get

Answer (score 1):

Use this one for date format, So you can give the input format and get output format also

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
 $fromdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```